# Wordpress breaks hyperlinks stored with the Options API

Tags: php, wordpress

I have a Wordpress theme that stores a copyright line in a Wordpress option using the `update_option` function.  In the text, I am including a link back to my website.

```
Copyright &copy; 2015 ABC Company, Inc.  Site design by <a href="http://www.example.com">My Company</a>.
```

That information is then retrieved in the theme's footer.

```
<p id="footer-copyright"><?php echo get_option('copyright'); ?></p>
```

However, the link appears as `http://www.blogsite.com/"http://www.example.com/"`.  I am assuming that internally Wordpress is trying to create an absolute url from what it believes to be a page slug.  How can I stop this behavior?  I have examined the `get_options` function defined in `wp-includes/options.php` and determined that it is not the problem.  The problem is occurring later in the theme processing.

### Edit:

Per David's suggestion, I have check the DB.  The value of this option is being altered before being written.  HTML entities are being parsed and quotes are being escaped.  Here is the actual value in the DB.

```
Copyright © 2015 ABC Company, Inc.  All rights reserved. Site design by <a href=\"http://www.example.com\">My Company</a>.
```

When I manually correct this in the DB, it displays fine.  Wordpress is performing some sort of post processing or parsing before writing the option value to the DB.

Comment: I think it has to do something by update_option($post_id,'copyright',$value);  This is either not doing it right or some other function is hooking into this.

Comment: not a wp issue, its doesnt attempt to validate urls or modify them. check your theme for the link above but also watch out for `/` or any relative operators within the url or in the theme template

Comment: @David I'm pretty sure it is a WP issue.  It happens in any theme.

Comment: well check the db is it saved there correctly?

Comment: @David No.  It's being altered.  The double quotes are being escaped before writing to the DB.  If I manually correct it, it displays fine.  But any attempt to alter it from within Wordpress results in the same bad escaped data being written back to the DB.

Comment: @David It's also converting HTML entities.  My text contains `&copy;` but it appears in the DB as a literal copyright symbol.

Comment: Never be a wordpress issue.. 100% its theme.. there is no place in WP to input copyright text, it'd be your theme configuration screen..

Comment: @mahaidery Thank you.  But it is in fact a Wordpress issue.  I'm currently debugging it and have it narrowed down to Wordpress' `sanitize_option` function.

Comment: If you could share the part of code it might help getting to the root cause?

Comment: @mahaidery I've already posted all relevant code.  I've also just posted the solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Wordpress unnecessarily escapes quotes in the option value during it's sanitizing process. The easiest solution is to use the [pre_update_option_(option name) hook](https://codex.wordpress.org/Plugin_API/Filter_Reference/pre_update_option_(option_name)) to process and remove the unnecessary escape characters before the value is written to the database.  This hook can be implemented in your theme's `functions.php` file.  (`NAME` in all caps should be replaced by the name of the option defined elsewhere in the `update_option` function.

```
function myplugin_update_option_NAME( $new_value, $old_value ) {
    $new_value = str_replace('\"', '"', $new_value);   // replaces \" with "
    return $new_value;
}

function myplugin_init() {
    add_filter( 'pre_update_option_NAME', 'myplugin_update_option_NAME', 10, 2 );
}

add_action( 'init', 'myplugin_init' );
```

I've intentionally avoided using PHP's `stripslashes` function in order to keep the code simple and avoid checking for magic quotes.

Wordpress is not actually prepending anything to the hyperlink destination.  However, because the hyperlink is not recognized with escaped quotes, it is treated as though it were a relative link causing the described behavior.